# How to simplify $\frac x{|x|}

Tags: absolute-value

Is there a simplification for this relation?

$$ \frac{x}{\left| x\right| } $$

where $x=a+i b$, $a$ and $b$ are reals.

Comment: Assuming $x\neq 0$ (so that the division is valid) you can write this as $\dfrac{a+ib}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$... though I'm not sure if you consider this simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By polar form $x=|x|e^{i\theta}$ we obtain

$$\frac{x}{\left| x\right| }=e^{i\theta}$$

with $\theta = \operatorname {atan2} \left(b, a \right)$ (see [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)).

Comment: $\operatorname {atan2} \frac b a$ makes no sense. If you are referring to [2-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) then it should be $\operatorname {atan2}(b, a)$.

Comment: Yes of course! I fix that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $x \neq 0$, you can reduce it to:-

$e^{i\theta}$, where

$\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac b a)$ if $a > 0$

$\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac b a) + \pi$ if $a<0$

$\theta = \frac \pi 2$ if $a=0$ and $b>0$

$\theta = -\frac \pi 2$ if $a=0$ and $b<0$

Comment: There is also the case $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$ to consider (+1).

Comment: Edit your answer to include @user case

Comment: We have $\theta = \frac \pi 2$ if $a=0$ and $b>0$, $\theta =- \frac \pi 2$ if $a=0$ and $b<0$.

Answer (score 2):

any complex number say '$z$' can be written in the form of : $z = a + ib$

so we define a function $f(z) = \frac{z}{|z|} \,\, (z \not= 0)\,\,$ then we can show that : $$f(a+ib) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}} + i\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}}  = cos(\theta) + sin(\theta) = \cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})) + i\sin(tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})) $$

[image]